# c++, mfc - messagebox display, main window has a cancel button. prevent cancel while messagebox is active

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, messagebox

I have a queer sort of problem. Consider the following scenario:

- Main window creates a child dialog on click of some button.
- Child dialog does some task in a worker thread.
- An error occurs during that task causing a message box to be displayed saying something along the lines of "Yikes! Something went wrong.".
- Child dialog's 'Cancel' button is clicked on causing the child dialog to be closed.
- Message box is still active! Clicking on anything in the message box = crash.

Pseudocode of how things are happening: (please ignore syntactic correctness here)

```
MainWindowClass mainObj;

void MainWindowClass::OnSomeButtonClick()
{
    SomeDialogClass someDialogObj;
    someDialogObj.DoModal();
}

int MainWindowClass::doTask()
{
    // Do work
    if(ERROR)
    {
        MessageBox("Yikes! Something went wrong.", "Error", MB_OK);
        return ERROR;
    }
} 

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Meanwhile, in another file,

extern MainWindowClass mainObj;

void SomeDialogClass::OnCancel()
{
    // Do all cleanup and close dialog
}

int SomeDialogClass::workerThreadFunc()
{
    return mainObj.doTask();
}

int SomeDialogClass::DoModal()
{
    AfxBeginThread(workerThreadFunc);
    // Do all other work and then wait for the worker thread
}
```

My question is twofold:

1. On cancel, is there a way to know if any message boxes/dialogs in
   the same application are active?
2. Is my entire design wrong and should I be doing something else altogether?

I thought one of the main reasons to use a modal dialog was its ability to prevent focus from going to parent dialogs. Yet, when that error message box is shown, I can happily click on the dialog and then click on 'Cancel' and pretend that the error message box never showed.

Comment: I suspect that on Cancel things aren't being cleaned up properly, and therefore you get a crash.

Comment: @TonyTheLion, The crash doesn't occur if I dismiss the error **before** clicking on 'Cancel'. The crash occurs because the `IsWindow()` assert fails for the message box.

Comment: so what is your question then?

Comment: "On cancel, is there a way to know if any message boxes/dialogs in the same application are active?"

Comment: @TonyTheLion, I'm so sorry for shooting down your suggestion. I made some dumb assumptions. Should I post my results as answer/question/comment? Thanks for your comment btw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than have your worker thread bring up a modal message box, it should signal the error condition back to the UI thread.  My experience of MFC and multi-threading is that having all UI handled in the same thread makes things much simpler and removes these types of error.  Having two threads potentially bringing up modal dialogs at the same time is asking for trouble.

Comment: Oh this sounds like a vastly better design than mine. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Made the exact same mistake when I started mixing multi-threading with MFC myself a few years ago, and had many crashes. Robust multi-threading is much more work than it appears at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of new at this, but my suggestions would be if the child is going to be cancelled when there is an error then destroy it before launching the error.

As far as I can tell, the SomeDialogClass is modal, then the parent launches another modal dialog, the MessageBox. Now, if SomeDialogClass was modeless then the message box would appear on top since SomeDialogClass would then be a child of the entire desktop and the sole child of MainWindowClass would be the MessageBox.

I'm under the impression that modal only prevents focus from going to things underneath the modal dialog, not what is launched on top or after it is open. I've done a modal dialog, launched a modeless from it, and could move both around the screen just fine. Additionally, I created a WM_MESSAGE from the modeless dialog back to the modal to announce when it was done so the modeless could finish.

Comment: Actually your suggestion was exactly what was happening. Child dialog always closed before the error showed. I thought that the message box being alive caused the crash, but I was wrong. What was happening was that after `SomeDialogClass::OnCancel()` was cleaned up all allocated memory, `SomeDialogClass::workerThreadFunc()` tried to access some of it (my example above was over-simplified, apologies). This was what caused the crash. But anyway, thank you for your suggestion! I will definitely keep it in mind for my next design!

Comment: Also, you were slightly off about modal dialogs. Modal dialogs only prevent their _parents_ from stealing focus. A parent is the calling object (and in turn the calling object of the calling object and so on). It doesn't matter which was drawn first or is underneath as such.